# OpenCV showing extra windows with black bar?

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu

I am working with OpenCV on Python and just from yesterday I encountered a very weird problem.

When I call a very simple method, `imshow()`, the program always spawn additional windows which has the same name as the main one and a black bar at the central.

Sometime, there is no extra window called, while sometime there are like 50 or 100 windows spawns in forever loop.

It is very strange and I encountered it since yesterday, when I uninstalled the opencv-python library and downloaded opencv-contrib-python. The first time I had this problem, the console log also gave me warning about the lack of GTK-Cambera module

```
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
```

However, I did try to fix it and download libraries on Ubuntu so that the warning is gone now. Furthermore, I try to reverse the opencv library by remove opencv-contrib-python and reuse opencv-python instead. Unfortunately, the problem still occurs.

In addition, I have a feeling that the more power the programs need, the more chance the "additional window" will appear.

The code I implemented:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(4)

while(cap.isOpened()):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Here is the image of the error:

[image: Error showing]

Comment: _when I uninstalled the opencv-python library and downloaded opencv-contrib-python._ What was the change for?

Comment: I want to use ximgproc module :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but are you using opencv 4.3 by any chance? I had the same problem, so I just downgraded to 4.2.

Comment: Yes, i am using 4.3.  I will try your solution now!

Comment: Thank you so much! You just saved my day!

Comment: Sorry I cannot upvote (low reputation) @@ Best for you and have a great day! Also, this is the correct solution. Still, I hope the OpenCV community will find way to fix this problem.