# OpenCV-Python imshow() is whack

Tags: python, opencv

- This is about OpenCV-Python on ubuntu 20.04
- It's a hit or miss with regards to imshow() displaying images/frames.
- When I run my code, sometimes the windows display, sometimes they don't, and other times only particular windows show up.
- Here are visuals of my conundrum (I rearrange the windows just to show):

1. 1/4 images displayed properly [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FxNH.png)
2. 0/4 images displayed properly [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfw5x.png)
3. 1/4 images displayed properly [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4q82r.png) <- Different image this time
4. 0/4 images displayed properly [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Df4gh.png)
5. 2/4 images displayed properly [libk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qabdl.png)

- Here is a simplified version of my code (which has the same problems):

```
    import cv2 as cv

    img = cv.imread('messi5.jpg')
    img2 = cv.imread('drawing.png')
    img3 = cv.imread('sudoku.jpg')

    cv.imshow('Original image', img)
    cv.imshow('Original drawing', img2)
    cv.imshow('Sudoku', img3)

    cv.waitKey(0)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

- That's it. Whenever I use my window machines, my OpenCV-Python codes/programs work without such issues.
- Also, I keep getting this message in the run console whenever I'm doing OpenCV-Python stuff on my Ubuntu machine:

```
Qt: Session management error: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported
```

Comment: Are you using opencv 4.3? If so, see [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63223103/10807234)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV showing extra windows with black bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223020/opencv-showing-extra-windows-with-black-bar)

Comment: Yes indeed it has.